# MySQL Load Data Query: Issue with Backslash ( \ )

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have I have a huge `csv` file with `149 column` and `25K+ rows` to upload this file in `MySQL` table I am using `MySQL LOAD DATA Query`
MY Query is:

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE '/Dir/file.csv' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

My query is working fine, the problem comes when my file has any `Backslash (\)` characters, the column value get disturb and file cell value not inserting in correct columns. is there any fix for this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
LOAD DATA local INFILE '/Dir/file.csv' INTO TABLE my_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\b' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Use '\b' as escape character instead of '\' in your query.